# How can I stop MacVim showing a whole screen of extra scroll?

Tags: vim, macvim

Whenever I load files into MacVim it seems to retain the full screen full of ~ lines.

This means that scroll is always out by a complete screen which is fairly annoying. Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

I have the following set in my ~/.gvimrc

```
set guioptions-=L
set guioptions-=r
set guioptions-=T
```

This removes the toolbar, scroll bars etc.

You can still scroll the page, but the bar doesn't show. For some reason you can't string all these options together. See: http://code.google.com/p/macvim/issues/detail?id=161

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If you scroll with trackpad or mouse middle button, the problem will still be there.